# Missing required parameters for [Route: patients.destroy] [URI: {language}/patients/{patient}]. (resources/views/patient/index.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, form-post

This is my code of index.blade.php
I tried everything with `app()->getLocale() but unfortunately with no positive result.
How can i fix it ?

```
<form action="{{ route('patients.destroy', $patient->id) }}" method="post" style="float: right;">
@csrf
@method('DELETE')
<button type="submit" style="border: 0; background: none; cursor: pointer;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
</form>
```

```
Route::redirect('/', '/en');
 Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}'], function() { 
        Route::get('/', function () { 
            return view('welcome'); 
        }); 
        Auth::routes(); 
        Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home'); 
        Route::resource('patients', 'PatientController'); 
        Route::get('/search', 'PatientController@search'); 
    });
```

Comment: What error are you facing? where are you using getLocale?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question doesn't give enough information on what you want to do

Comment: Please post your route definition. Looks like you have a language parameter that you are not passing to the route helper function.

Comment: I try to access en / patients and it gives me the error in Missing required parameters for [Route: patients.destroy] [URI: {language} / patients / {patient}].
if I delete this form, it allows me to access patients

Comment: Route::redirect('/', '/en');

Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}'], function() {
 
 Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('welcome');
 });

 Auth::routes();

 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

 Route::resource('patients', 'PatientController');
 Route::get('/search', 'PatientController@search');

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route is expecting two params, and you passed only one so change your route as below.

```
<form action="{{ route('patients.destroy', ['language'=>'en','id'=>$patient->id]) }}" method="post" style="float: right;">
```

Edit:-

For welcome blade you directly access the URL `<a href="{{ url('en') }}"`

Or if you want to do it with route then you need to assign the name as below

```
Route::get('/', function () { 
   return view('welcome'); 
})->name('welcome');
<a href="{{ route('welcome',app()->getLocale ()) }}"></a>
```

Comment: I still bother you a little :)) .. How can I create a <a> what does root to / patients?
if it does href = "{{route ('home', app () -> getLocale ())}}" error Route [patients] not defined.

Comment: / en or / other language / patients I try to access with that a, but I can't handle it :)) ..

Comment: `href = "{{ route ('patients.index', app () -> getLocale ()) }}"`

Comment: one more question, which I can't handle here, how do I put an <a> in welcome.blade.php with href to root to / en?

Comment: How can I create a href route to edit a patient according to the patient's respective id, so that I can find that route and the language selected by the user?

Comment: {{ route ('patients.edit', ['id'=>$patientid, 'language'=>app () -> getLocale ()]) }}

Comment: You can do one thing to know more about how to set route in href as if you run this command in your route you'll get all route list with convenient url php artisan route:list

Comment: I know about php artisan route: list, but I don't know exactly how to put it into practice, now after I access the patient's edit, it gives me 404 error :)) ..: -?

Comment: Hi, i have another problem, if you want to help me "Missing required parameters for [Route: users.destroy] [URI: {language}/users/destroy/{$user->id}]. (View: /Users/cristim1x/Documents/laravel/cv/resources/views/users.blade.php)" <a href="{{route('users.destroy',['id'=>$user->id])}}" class = "btn btn-danger">Delete</a>